# "define" not defined error when trying to upgrade from 3.2.5 to 4.1.10

Tags: javascript, requirejs, tinymce

I'm trying to upgrade tinymce from 3.2.5 to 4.1.10 in my program and when I add the new libs, I get the error "define not defined" in every utils file.
After Googling I saw that define is part of RequireJS. That means I'm obliged to import requireJS in order to use tinyMCE? Can I just avoid that? I don't want to use requireJS.

For example this XHR class

```
define("tinymce/util/XHR", [
    "tinymce/util/Observable",
    "tinymce/util/Tools"
], function(Observable, Tools) {
```

Any help would be much appreciated.